# The seminorm of $L^{p,\infty}$ does not fulfill the triangular inequality.

Tags: real-analysis, lp-spaces, integral-inequality

Hello I am attending a course of harmonic analysis. My professor pointed out a fact about $L^{p,\infty}(\mathbb{R^{d}})$ spaces, leaving the proof to us, and I got stuck. It is not an assignment of any kind, he simply stated it as a curiosity.
The fact is the following: given two functions $f,g \in L^{p,\infty}$ then we have
$$ \left\Vert f +g  \right\Vert_{p,\infty} \leq c_{p} \left[ \, \left\Vert f \right\Vert_{p,\infty}+ \left\Vert g \right\Vert_{p,\infty} \right]$$
where $c_{p}=\max\left\{ 2,2^{\frac{1}{p}}\right\}$ and
$$ \left\Vert f \right\Vert_{L^{p,+\infty}}:=\inf \left\{ c : \mathcal{L}(\left\{ \left| f \right|>\lambda \right\}) < \frac{c^{p}}{\lambda^{p}} \forall  \lambda>0 \right\}$$
obviously $\mathcal{L}$ is the $d-$dimensional Lebesgue measure. I proceded as follows:
Given $\epsilon>0$
$$ \mathcal{L}\left( \{ \left\vert f +g \right\vert > \lambda \} \right) \leq \mathcal{L}(\{ \vert f \vert> \frac{\lambda}{2} \})+\mathcal{L}(\{ \vert g \vert> \frac{\lambda}{2} \}) \\
\leq \frac{2^{p}\left( \Vert f \Vert_{p,\infty} +\epsilon \right)^p}{\lambda^{p}}+\frac{2^{p}\left( \Vert g \Vert_{p,\infty} +\epsilon \right)^p}{\lambda^{p}}.$$
As a consequence, we obtain that for every $\epsilon>0$
$$ \Vert f+g \Vert_{p,\infty} \leq 2 \, \left[ (\Vert f\Vert_{p,\infty} +\epsilon )^{p} + (\Vert g\Vert_{p,\infty} +\epsilon )^{p} \right]^{\frac{1}{p}}.$$ How can I conclude? I am only able to prove the inequality for $c_{p}=2.$ Moreover is the constant $c_{p}$ sharp? Are there any functions for which we have the equality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When $p\geq1$ you have, for $a,b>0$,
$$
(a^p+b^p)^{1/p}\leq a+b, 
$$
and you are done. When $p<1$, you can use
$$
(a^p+b^p)^{1/p}\leq 2^{1/p} (a+b).
$$

Comment: I did not notice that p could also be less than one!